# Посчитать диагональ прямоугольника

Tags: rust

Расшыряю листинг 5.13 из книги по Rust.

**Задача**: сделать метод, возвращающий диагональ прямоугольника, если сторона заданы как u32

**Код**:

```
// File : rs_book_listing_5.13.rs
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn s(&self) -> u32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
    fn p(&self) -> u32 {
        2 * self.width + 2 * self.height
    }
    fn d(&self) -> f64 {
        ((&self.width as &f64).powf(2.0) * (&self.height as &f64).powf(2.0)).sqrt()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let rect1 = Rectangle {
        width: 30,
        height: 50,
    };

    println!(
        "\
Aria: {}
Perimeter: {}
Diagonal: {}",
        rect1.s(),
        rect1.p(),
        rect1.d(),
    );
}
// End of rs_book_listing_5.13.rs
```

Не могу разобраться в переходах по типам, метод  sqrt() требует а32 или f64, помогает изменить тип для width и height на f32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем пытаться брать `self.width` по ссылке? Это небольшие [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) поля, их копирование по значению крайне дешево (в `s` и `p` методах они уже по значению копируются):

```
fn d(&self) -> f64 {
    ((self.width as f64).powf(2.0) * (self.height as f64).powf(2.0)).sqrt()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d4f846a558c6c8674df337e00e126ebe&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

> метод `sqrt()` требует `f32` или `f64`

Да, взятие квадратного корня в стандартной библиотеке [предоставляется только для чисел с плавающей точкой](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=sqrt), так что и правда надо или сразу хранить поля в этих типах, или приводить к ним в рассчетах.

Comment: Как по книге делал. Я еще плаваю...

Comment: У меня не считало почему то, выдавало только результат произведения без степеней и корня. По ссылке есть уже готовый метод `pub fn hypot(self, other: f64) -> f64` он и помог, надо бы сразу документацию читать а не по книге тащится быстрей будет :)